# Are there any good pure java browser emulators.?

Tags: java

Some basic stuff it should have include...

- Must support local http/https traffic optimisation.
- Must support limiting the amount of javascript execution.

Comment: I'm guessing that by "browser emulator" you just mean "browser" right?

Comment: as DaoWen asked, not sure what "browser emulator" means. We are developing https://gngr.info as a pure Java browser.

Answer (score 2):

[Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) is a browser written completely in Java. Since it's open source you could do whatever you want to limit JavaScript. However, I'm thinking the code base is probably larger than what you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nother one, called [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). I guess it is a bit better.